# Cannot change checkbox color API 19

Tags: android, checkbox

I'm trying to change checkbox color on Api <21 like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/chSave"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:buttonTint="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtterms" />
```

also tried setting theme like this:

```
<style name="checkBoxStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffff</item>
</style>


<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/chSave"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:theme="@style/checkBoxStyle"
            app:buttonTint="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtterms" />
```

and also tried with just `CheckBox` without appcompat.

Layout is in `DialogFragment`, tried changing it to `AppCompatDialogFragment`, changing theme to `appcompat` but none of it helped.

Using custom drawable is a last resort. 
So is there any other chance to achieve this?

Comment: once try android:theme="@style/checkBoxStyle"

Comment: <style name="MyCheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/foo</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/bar</item>
</style>

Comment: Will this be of any help? https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/Switch

Comment: @AashutoshKumar tried that, no luck :(

Comment: @Stallion trying to avoid custom controls for now, but if nothing works I'll keep that in mind. Thanks

Comment: are you added dependency 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:X.X.X' // where X.X.X version

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a test on an app with minimum api 16 and this worked, though you see it filled in with the color when checked="true", when it is false, only the borders are red.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        app:buttonTint="@color/colorRed"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not working for me, no idea why :(

Comment: can you post your manifest regarding what api are you targeting, compiling, etc?

Comment: Target api is 25, midsdk - 16, compile is same as target. I'm out of office, will post manifest xml when I get back.